# Understanding constraintBottom and constraintBaseline

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Among all the ConstraintLayout attributes available in Android Studio 2.2, there are these two *Bottom* constrains and a *Baseline* constrain:

`layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf`
`layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf`
`layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf`

And it seems that not every view has baseline.

What's the difference and similarities between Bottom and Baseline constrain? Why do only certain views have a Baseline?

The [official](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.html) [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) lacks this kind of information.

**EDIT**
This image helps to understand baseline vs base:
[image: Baseline is the text's base inside a view. It is between the top and the bottom.]
[image: Text and bottom-with-text baseline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseline is used for make view bottom to bottom of text

for example in EditText the text is not the bottom so
if you use baseline it will be in bottom of

EditText's **text** not EditText's **view**

[image]

more info from [android developer training official website](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)