# What are the differences between layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf, layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf and layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am looking at the page for constraintlayout https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout for android studio but I can't find the section where it gives me the purpose of each layout constrain and in what circumstances it should be used, it only shows you all the available layout constrains but I can't find anything in more detail than that for each one, does anyone know where to find this information?

Answer (score 0):

`layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` is used in `ConstraintLayout` to align the end of one view to the end of another view.

`layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` is used in `ConstraintLayout` to align the bottom of one view to the bottom of another view.

`layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf` is an attribute used in `ConstraintLayout` to align the baseline of one view to the baseline of another view. Baseline refers to the text baseline, which is an imaginary line that text characters rest on, and is not necessarily at the bottom of the view.

This attribute is used to align the text baseline of two views, so that their text appears vertically aligned.

For example, you could use `layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf` to align the text baseline of a `TextView` with the text baseline of an `EditText`, ensuring that their text aligns even if they have different font sizes.

Comment: what are the differences between, the bottom, the baseline and the end of a view?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802390/understanding-constraintbottom-and-constraintbaseline